# My Favicon is not showing I have tried everything possible

Tags: html, favicon, .ico

[vscode snapshot of html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMwoI.png)

It is Not working on any browser Brave,chrome,firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A favicon is a graphic image (icon) associated with a particular Web page and/or Web site. Many recent user agents (such as graphical browsers and newsreaders) display them as a visual reminder of the Web site identity in the address bar or in tabs.

The format for the image you have chosen must be 16x16 pixels or 32x32 pixels, using either 8-bit or 24-bit colors.

Usually a common name for a favicon image is `favicon.ico`

```
<link rel="icon" 
      type="image/x-icon" 
      href="/somewhere/favicon.ico" />
```

With the introduction of smartphone tablet and other devices, things have changed, and to get a correct and complete solution that works on any device is really time-consuming.

Thus, websites such as https://www.favicon-generator.org/ were born and create all the necessary

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/apple-icon-57x57.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/apple-icon-60x60.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/apple-icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/apple-icon-76x76.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/apple-icon-114x114.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/apple-icon-120x120.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/apple-icon-144x144.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/apple-icon-152x152.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-icon-180x180.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192"  href="/android-icon-192x192.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="/favicon-96x96.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/ms-icon-144x144.png">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
```

Since you uploaded a screenshot, it is difficult to see where the problem lies. Whether in the image size or a path problem

Comment: It's a 32x32 image and for path when I click on the image address in the code it takes me to the image which I guess is a green flag